# Spawning child_process in NodeJS with valid HOME folder set

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm trying to spawn a process in NodeJS that accesses the my home folder, and can't see, to get either of the options below to work.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    options = {stdio: 'inherit', env: process.env};

spawn('ls', ['~/'], options);
spawn('ls', ['$HOME'], options);
```

**Output**

```
ls: ~/: No such file or directory
ls: $HOME: No such file or directory
```

I've verified that `options.env.HOME` is properly set, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

So this is what I ended up doing to make my use-case work (using `script` instead of `ls`):

```
spawn('script', [process.env.HOME], options);
```

Then, inside of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export HOME=$1
```

I still don't understand why `options.env.HOME` does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: You want `spawn('ls', [process.env.HOME], options);`

Comment: Thanks @generalhenry but this was just an example. My actual command runs `docker pull` which needs access to `~/.dockercfg`.

Comment: Why not just use dockerode? https://github.com/apocas/dockerode#equivalent-of-docker-pull-in-dockerode

Comment: I looked at it earlier, don't think it supports building from a Dockerfile with a local context. I really would like to know how to use `spawn` correctly however ;)

Comment: It does, you simply need to replicate the behavior of the command line client, aka turn the folder into a tar and stream it into the build. As for the spawn you might try setting the cwd.

Comment: Yeah I am setting `cwd` already to the working directory I want the script to operate in so that won't work either. Thanks though.

Comment: @generalhenry thanks for your help, I finally got something to work by setting HOME inside of my script and passing it in as you mentioned. Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process.env.HOME is what you want. Use it like so:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    options = {stdio: 'inherit'};

var ls = spawn('ls', [process.env.HOME]);

ls.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(String(data));
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(String(data));
});
```

Then you can set HOME in your shell when invoking the node script:

```
HOME='/tmp'; node ls.js
```

Alternatively, you don't have to overload HOME. To use whatever variable you like export it first, and then access it through process.env.:

```
export FOO='/tmp'; node ls.js
```

Comment: Home is already set correctly when I invoke `node ls.js`. However, as I mentioned in my update above it's when I `spawn` a child_process that I cannot seem to set it anymore. I found a solution (more of a hack) as described above.

Comment: Could you please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856162/how-to-map-docker-directories-from-an-electron-vue-frontend

I have a feeling you could solve that one too! :)